# Modify list item marker (bullet) property

Tags: css, list

i have this simple **CSS** code and I am wondering if there is a way to set the text property of a bullet (in this case, numerical item markers: 1,2,3,etc) to a specific dimension and colour without changing the dimension of all the elements inside  `li`

```
ol {
   background: #3399ff;
   padding: 20px;
   }
ol li {
     background: #cce5ff;
     color: green;
     font-size: 40px;
     }
```

Comment: `ol li:nth-child(1) {color: black}`, `ol li:nth-child(2) {color: red}` etc...

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with `:before` pseudo-element and [`css counter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Lists_and_Counters/Using_CSS_counters).

```css
ol {
  background: #3399ff;
  padding: 20px;
  counter-reset: ol-counter;
  list-style-type: none;
}
ol li {
  background: #cce5ff;
  color: green;
}
li::before {
  counter-increment: ol-counter;
  content: counter(ol-counter)". ";
  font-size: 40px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
  <li>Li</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I partially agree with your suggestion, but I observed that initially the markers were a part of  `ol`. Your solution inserts the markers in the `li` frames. tnx anyway!